# Shopify liquid template: repeat HTML code only once

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

I could successfully add a second hard coded `store address` in my Shopify template. Now, I'm attempting to add a second `address`.

The challenge I'm facing is this hard coded address is getting repeated because of a `for` loop which binds the value from the `settings.json` file.

The hard coded address is getting repeated three times, since it is being considered by the for loop. But the `for` loop cannot be removed, because it binds the first address, contact, and visiting hours.

I've tried using an `if` block with with my hard code, but it didn't work out.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container main content main-wrapper">
  {% if section.settings.image == nil %}
    <h1 class="center">{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <div class="feature_divider"></div>
  {% endif %}

  <div class="sixteen columns featured_links">
    <div class="section clearfix feature">
      {% for block in section.blocks %}
        <div class="{% if section.settings.featured_promos_per_row == 2 %}eight columns {% cycle 'alpha', 'omega' %}{% elsif section.settings.featured_promos_per_row == 3 %}one-third column {% cycle 'alpha', '', 'omega' %}{% else %}four columns {% cycle 'alpha', '', '', 'omega' %}{% endif %} {% if section.settings.featured_links_style != blank %}{{ section.settings.featured_links_style }} {% cycle 'delay-025s', 'delay-05s', 'delay-075s', 'delay-1s' %}{% endif %} center">
          {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
            <a href="{{ block.settings.link }}">
          {% endif %}

          <div class="{% if section.settings.rounded_image != blank %}rounded{% endif %}">
            {% if block.settings.image != nil %}
              <img  src="{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '300x' }}"
                    alt="{{ block.settings.image.alt }}"
                    data-src="{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '2048x' }}"
                    class="lazyload"
                    {% comment %} data-sizes="auto" {% endcomment %}
                    data-srcset=" {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '2048x' }} 2048w,
                                  {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '1600x' }} 1600w,
                                  {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '1200x' }} 1200w,
                                  {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '1000x' }} 1000w,
                                  {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '800x' }} 800w,
                                  {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '600x' }} 600w,
                                  {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '400x' }} 400w"
                     />
            {% else %}
              {% capture i %}{% cycle "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" %}{% endcapture %}
              {{ 'collection-' | append: i | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg placeholder-svg--promotions' }}
            {% endif %}
          </div>

          {% if block.settings.title != blank %}
            <h3>{{ block.settings.title | escape }}</h3>
            {% if section.settings.show_divider %}
              <div class="feature_divider"></div>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
          {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
            </a>
          {% endif %}

          {% if block.settings.text != blank %}
            {{ block.settings.text }}
          {% endif %}

        {% if section.blocks===1%}
        <div class="store-new">
          <br><p>XYZ</p><p>XYZ,<br>XYZ<br>XYZ</p>
        </div>
         {% endif %}        

        </div>

        {% if section.settings.featured_promos_per_row == 2 %}
          {% cycle '', '<br class="clear " />' %}
        {% elsif section.settings.featured_promos_per_row == 3 %}
          {% cycle '', '', '<br class="clear" />' %}
        {% else %}
          {% cycle '', '', '', '<br class="clear" />' %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% if section.settings.contact_address != blank %}
    <br class="clear" />
    <div class="embed-container maps">
        <iframe width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q={{ section.settings.contact_address | replace: ' ', '+' }}&amp;z={{ section.settings.zoom_level }}&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>


</div>
```

Can someone please help me understand why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
{{ if forloop.index0 == 1 }}
```

or

```
{{ if forloop.index == 2 }}
```

instead of

```
{% if section.blocks===1%}
```